# php command not found after PHP8 install on OpenSUSE Leap 15.4

Tags: linux, php, opensuse, zypper

I have upgraded my OpenSUSE Leap from 15.3 to 15.4.

I then want to upgrade PHP from version 7 to version 8. Before upgrade, PHP version is:

```
server:~ # php -v
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Nov  3 2022 12:00:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I first started with a classic installation:

```
server:~ # zypper install php8
```

After installation is done (no particular errors/warnings mentionned), I get this:

```
server:~ # php -v
-bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

I then followed the [official documentation](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=php8&project=home%3Ailluusio%3Aphp-next) for packages management which suggests to add a specific repository. I just added option `-r 1` to the `install` command to specify the repository ID I want to install from:

```
server:~ # zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:illuusio:php-next/15.4/home:illuusio:php-next.repo
server:~ # zypper refresh
server:~ # zypper install -r 1 php8
```

After installation is done (no particular errors/warnings mentionned), I now get this:

```
server:~ # php -v
php: command not found
```

Both installations processes suggest to **uninstall** PHP7, which I did accept (I don't want to keep both php7 and php8 on my server).

I then checked these:

```
srv-dev01:~ # whereis php
php: /usr/share/php

srv-dev01:~ # ll /usr/share/php
total 0
```

I don't understand why php8 is not properly installed... I guess a link is probably needed in `/usr/bin/` directory but, if so, I don't get why it is not done by the installation process... I'd like to do an install as clean as possible.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the php-cli package.

```
zypper install php8-cli
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks... I still don't get why this package is not within default installation.